# unable to get C-PGUP or C-PGDOWN key codes in tmux

Tags: key-bindings, tmux, gnome-terminal

in order to configure vim I need to be able to know C-PGUP and C-PGDOWN keycodes.

what I usually do is

```
Ctrl-V Ctrl-PGUP
```

or

```
Ctrl-V Ctrl-PG
```

this gives something like

```
^[[5;5~
```

or

```
^[[6;5~
```

outside of tmux.

when doing the same in tmux, nothing happens wit Ctrl-PGUP or ctrl-PGDOWN... as if the terminal was just not detecting I pressed those keys (Ctrl-V works fine with other key combinations)

FYI, I am running tmux inside gnome-terminal (same problem with xterm... must be a tmux configuration issue...).

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your tmux.conf just add the following line:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```